# Ubuntu (docker) cannot use DNS server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, docker

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 running inside a docker container.

I have a working network connection:

```
PING 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=71.3 ms
```

However I seem to be unable to resolve domain names:

```
ping: unknown host www.example.com
```

It should be using OpenDNS

```
>> cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

The OpenDNS IP addresses respond to ping

```
PING 208.67.222.222 (208.67.222.222) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 208.67.222.222: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=3.57 ms
```

But domain name resolution still isn't working.

What might be causing this, and how could I diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: Can you post the output of `nslookup google.com 208.67.222.222`?

Comment: `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: Can you try using Google's public DNS at `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`?

Comment: Google DNS doesn't work, however our own corporate DNS works - any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither OpenDNS or Google's DNS public DNS servers respond, you most likely have firewall rules preventing your server from making outbound requests on port 53.

I would check your local firewall rules, or your network's negress rules.

Comment: I'm using our own DNS now without any problems, so I think that must be it.